# Plotting two dictionaries with Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a problem going on. I tried to plot two dictionaries (with the same (number of) keys, but different values) in one graph. The idea is to make a line graph containing two lines; both dictionaries. The x-axis will be the dictionary keys, where the y-axis will be the values in both dicts. I managed to plot using

`plt.plot(range(len(dict1)), dict1.values())
 plt.plot(range(len(dict2)), dict2.values())`

When i run the plot, it shows indeed two lines. But the x axis ticks (the keys from the dict (one or the other) are not sorted, while they were when I printed the dictionaries. I know this is due to the fact that getting the dict.values() creates an unsorted list. But when I change the plot data to this instead:
`plt.plot(range(len(dict1)), sorted(dict1.values()))`, the values shown in the plot won't change with it. The xticks are finally ordered, but the line graph does not match the right value anymore. How can I bypass this?

Comment: You need to sort the values by the key, not the value.

Comment: I plot two `dict`s in the morning, I plot two `dict`'s at night [...] and at every 10,000 points, I plot two `dict`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionaries are unordered, so when you call `keys` or `values` and even sort them, they won't necessarily be in any order. However, when you call `keys` and `values` together and if the dictionary is not being modified, the lists returned by both these functions will contain the 'key:value' pairs in the same indexes. If keys in the dictionaries are numbers, then you can do this:

```
plt.plot(list(dict1.keys()), list(dict1.values()))
```

This converts the keys and values to lists, so you can use them as x and y values.

Comment: They are floats, containing a date type

Comment: It does not work, because the keys in my dictionaries are floats. If not, it would indeed work: "ValueError: invalid literal for float()"

Comment: You asked `The x-axis will be the dictionary keys, where the y-axis will be the values`. Is this isn't want you want, what do you want?

Comment: That is right, but it won't work this way, because the dict keys are not the correct type. Setting the x-axis separately as xticks only works at the moment.

Comment: @J.Williams check my new answer. Add `list` around the keys and values

Comment: Let's [continue in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138772/discussion-between-jerfov2-and-j-williams).

Comment: Thank you @Jerfov2